# How to configure NAT in Cisco ASA Firewall for all VLANs connected to layer 3 switch?

Tags: vlan, cisco-asa, nat, firewall, packet-tracer

**Topology:**
[image]

How to set up NAT in Cisco ASA Firewall (in Packet Tracer), when there are VLANs in the network?

In the current approach, NAT is not working to reach the server (8.8.8.8) from any of the VLANs.

It is working if I ping from the layer3 switch (172.168.0.1).

*NOTE: When used Router instead of ASA Firewall, I was able to setup NAT in it, but I am first time working with ASA firewall.

current configuration:

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.0.2 255.255.0.0
!
interface Vlan3
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 51.1.1.1 255.0.0.0
!
object network LAN
 subnet 172.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 51.1.1.2 1
!
access-list local-to-internet extended permit tcp any any
access-list local-to-internet extended permit icmp any any
!
!
access-group local-to-internet in interface outside
object network LAN
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
```

*Download .pkt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dzZFb9S9S83wmQjTWAa2EBOxiwsV7GHg/view?usp=sharing*

Answer (score 1):

It's not just NAT but also routing in your case.
For NAT this should do:

```
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
```

For routing you will need to route "inside" networks to your inside router:

```
route inside 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.0.1
route inside 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.0.1
route inside 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.0.1
etc.
```

Without this, all subnets for vlans 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50... are going through default route (to outside interface) as no other routes are specified.
PS: Routers/switches

Comment: Where should I execute (on which interface or object network subnet, etc.) "nat" command ?

Comment: @Rajan Those are global commands.  Just enter them anywhere in config mode and they’ll go to the right place.

Comment: In ASA firewall "nat" command is only available while defining object network. I checked all available commands in the global config mode.

Comment: @Rajan The problem is that you’re doing this in Packet Tracer, which is just a learning tool and doesn’t support all of the functionality or commands of a real device.  @PJ7’s answer is valid (since your current NAT only covers the “LAN” network and not the rest of your private networks, but your virtual device is rejecting it because Packet Tracer is junk, essentially.

Comment: @Rajan NAT can be set globally or it can be defined on an object. The difference is the structure of the statement. In an object NAT, after you type nat (<int1>,<int2>) the next command is either dynamic or static; in a global NAT, the next command is either the position where you want it to sit in the NAT table, after-auto, or source. Depending on which of those statements you use, determines which type of NAT you’re entering. If you try to enter an object NAT while not inside of an object, it will reject the command; the inverse is not true of global NAT statements.

Comment: I understand what you are saying here, but problem is that I have to design network in Packet Tracer only. ASA Firewall present in Packet tracer don't have functionality to configure NAT in global config mode (It is there for other devices like Router), it is only possible using "object network". But even doing it using "object network" only static NAT is working, so I guess as you said Packet Tracer is not a good tool and this may be a bug.

Comment: @Rajan You can try other products such as Cisco VIRL or GNS3 if you’d like.  It might yield better results.